# Getting npm ERR! errno 199 when running Protractor with cucumber framework

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor, cucumberjs

I am new to JavaScript and Protractor both, I am using Protractor with cucmber js.
I am getting issue is below code :

```
Then(/^I verified all pages visible to logged in user$/, () => {

    var expVisibleNavPages = 'Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools,a';

    var NavLinks = element.all(by.css('ul.nav.navbar-nav')).get(0).all(by.css('a'));

    var len =0;

    NavLinks.then(function(result) {
            len = result.length;
            logger.info("TOTAL NAV LINKS ARE ARE:"+len);
        });


    var actVisibleNavPages = "";
    var iCt = 0;


    NavLinks.each(function (element) {

        element.getText().then(function(text){

        actVisibleNavPages += text+",";
        iCt++;

            if (len === iCt)
            {
                logger.info("ACTUAL PAGES:"+actVisibleNavPages);

                logger.info("EXPECTED PAGES:"+expVisibleNavPages);

                return expect(actVisibleNavPages).to.equal(expVisibleNavPages);
            }



        });


    });
```

I got bellow error:

> [2017-12-19T23:59:36.696] [INFO] default - TOTAL NAV LINKS ARE ARE:5
>   [2017-12-19T23:59:36.818] [INFO] default - ACTUAL PAGES:Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools,
>   [2017-12-19T23:59:36.821] [INFO] default - EXPECTED PAGES:Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools,a
>   [23:59:36] E/launcher - expected 'Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools,' to equal 'Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools,a'
>   [23:59:36] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected 'Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools,' to equal 'Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools,a'
>       at C:/HancockSoftwareAutomation/mdmf_automation_bdd/mdmf_e2e_gui_testing/stepDefinitions/navaigation_bar_steps.js:74:49
>       at elementArrayFinder_.then (C:\HancockSoftwareAutomation\mdmf_automation_bdd\mdmf_e2e_gui_testing\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:804:32)
>       at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\HancockSoftwareAutomation\mdmf_automation_bdd\mdmf_e2e_gui_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
>       at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\HancockSoftwareAutomation\mdmf_automation_bdd\mdmf_e2e_gui_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
>       at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\HancockSoftwareAutomation\mdmf_automation_bdd\mdmf_e2e_gui_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
>       at asyncRun (C:\HancockSoftwareAutomation\mdmf_automation_bdd\mdmf_e2e_gui_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
>       at C:\HancockSoftwareAutomation\mdmf_automation_bdd\mdmf_e2e_gui_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
>       **at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>   [23:59:36] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 199**

Because of npm errno 199, protractor process is getting terminated and is stop executing further scenarios.

Looking for help.

Comment: Try this:
> npm run update-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated code like below, and it worked:

```
Then(/^I verified all pages visible to logged in user$/, () => {

    var expVisibleNavPages = ["Home","Applications","Programs","Reports","Admin Tools","a"];

    let actVisibleNavPages =  element.all(by.css('ul.nav.navbar-nav')).get(0).all(by.css('a'));

     var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 200, actVisibleNavPages.getText());
    });


    return expect(promise).to.eventually.deep.equal(expVisibleNavPages);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error log is self-explained. Your script found only 5 "NavLinks", including Home,Applications,Programs,Reports,Admin Tools, while the expected value is 6 with another object called "a". This will cause an assertion error.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have intentionally made it to fail assertion. The question is if assertion failed then protractor should not quit and continue with other scenarios , but in this Protactor process is gettig killed with npm error 199. In other steps when an assertion failed then protrator failed that scenario and continue with next scenario.  so my question is how to avoid protracror process termination with assertion failure.

Comment: The error 199 seems to be an uncaught exception, so you can try to add the `ignoreUncaughtExceptions = true` property to your `protractor.config`. Then Protractor will proceed to next scenario when this assertion error occurs. Hopefully, it will work.